# Why is d3 keeping some of my elements when I want it to remove all of the elements?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make a very simple Fraction visualiser, Basically the user can put in a numerator and denominator, and d3 will show them boxes, blue for the numerator, and the rest white (empty/blank) when they click a button.
The function I'm using is below:

```
const redraw = function() {
  d3.select("frac")
    .selectAll("div")
    .data(window.dataset)
    .exit()
    .remove()
  d3.select("frac")
    .append("div")
    .selectAll("div").data(window.dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    /* .text((d)=>d) */
    .style("width", width / window.dataset.length + "vw")
    .style("background-color", (d) => {
      if (d == 0) {
        return "white"
      } else if (d == 1) {
        return "blue"
      } else if (d == 2) {
        return "red"
      } else if (d == 3) {
        return "yellow"
      }
    })
}
```

see full code here: https://jsfiddle.net/sbrevolution5/gpueyrtf/53/

For some reason when I update a number and redraw the d3 element, it keeps 2 blue boxes, but then creates the new element below.

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap the lines `.remove()` and `.exit()`.
So from:

```
    .exit()
    .remove()
```

change to

```
    .remove()
    .exit()
```

Comment: You don't need `selection.exit()` if you take this approach: the elements have already been removed from the DOM by `selection.remove()`. `exit` just returns a new selection, it doesn't modify the DOM. This answer's approach works, but limits some options as it avoids use of the canonical enter/update/exit cycle, instead favoring to remove everything and enter everything every update (which may or may not be desirable). *If the approach is preferred, then the `.data()` method is unnecessary as well: `d3.selectAll("selector").remove()` is sufficient to remove existing elements.*